# Key-Store Database / Doubles Conditions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to retrieve all the users ids who have their preferences (IN (1,7) AND (2)). Even without the group on user_id. It doesn't work. Any idea would be very helpful.

```
HasPreference.find(:all, :conditions  => ["preference_id IN (1,7) AND preference_id = 2"], :group  => :user_id)
```

TABLE is 'has_preferences'

```
ID -- PREFERENCE_ID -- USER_ID

1  --       2       --    1

1  --       7       --    1

1  --       1       --    1

1  --       2       --    2
```

I'd like to get [1] as a result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  user_id
FROM    has_preferences
WHERE   preference_id = 2
        AND user_id IN
        (
        SELECT  user_id
        FROM    has_preferences
        WHERE   preference_id IN (1, 7)
        )
```

Create an index on `(preference_id, user_id)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to translate this to Ruby but I believe following SQL Statement satisfies your requirement.

**SQL Statement**

```
SELECT  p.*
FROM    dbo.has_preferences p
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  User_ID
          FROM    dbo.has_preferences
          WHERE   Preference_ID IN (1, 7)
        ) pIN ON pIN.User_ID = p.User_ID
WHERE   p.Preference_ID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven! but It's not really what I'm looking for. I want "Users who have the preference 7 AND [X]". With [X] an array of IDs. SO it's "7 AND (id1 OR id2 OR id3)". 7 is required and one of the IDs too.

Comment: @Alextoul, I have no idea how it translates to ruby but I've edited the answer with how it could be done using SQL.

Comment: @Alextoul, your comment doesn't match your question, which says you are trying to retrieve all the users ids who have preferences "(IN (1,7) AND (2))" - ie. it's **2** and (1 or 7). Please can you clarify which condition is required?

Comment: @Mark, @Quassnoi & @lieven, thanks for your answer. Wouldn't have found this alone. It works.